# How to concatenate a int/float value with a string within double quotes using arduino ide

Tags: string, arduino, iot, esp32, gsm

I am trying to send my sensor data through gprs using esp32 and ai thinker a9 gsm module. I want a variable of type int/float (int) to be added between the string as follows:

post = ""{"nodeId": "32456781xxxxxxx", "value": {"temperature": int }}"";

problem i am facing is i am unable to add my post variable in double quotes as per requirement of AT commands.

For more info refer my output image and the problem i am facing which i need to be solved

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S2Hw.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtTnr.jpg)

i want that marked text between double quotes as shown in image 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

C++ and "Arduino" (to the extent that it can really be called a "language") don't do string interpolation.  You basically have to cobble the string together yourself using `snprintf` or `std::ostringstream` (which you'd have on the ESP32).  The Arduino `String` class also supports concatenation of non-string things onto the end of it.

Between the those options `snprintf` can probably be used more efficiently, something like this:

```cpp
int some_int_variable = 7; // for example
char post[REASONABLE_UPPER_BOUND]; 
snprintf(
    post, sizeof post, 
    R"xyzzy({"nodeId": "32456781xxxxxxx", "value": {"temperature": %d }})xyzzy",
    some_int_variable
);

// do something with resulting post variable.
```

If you're wondering what the `R"xyzzy(`, and `)xyzzy"`, it's a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), an alternative to escaping the double quotes.

That said, since you're working with JSON, it *may* make a lot more sense to use [ArduinoJSON](https://arduinojson.org/) to construct your JSON object in an ArduinoJSON document as you can see [in this example](https://arduinojson.org/v6/example/generator/).  They're serializing it to a stream; if you're using `StaticJsonDocument`, this may not require any dynamic (re)allocation(s).  If you actually need it to result in a String (and you may not actually) you can see how that is done [here](https://arduinojson.org/v6/example/string/).

Answer (score 0):

Add a backslash before inerr double quotes, something like this:

```
"\"{\"nodeId\": \"32456781xxxxxxx\", \"value\": {\"temperature\": int }}\""
```